# QGraphicsPathItem issue with computing boundingRect

Tags: python, pyside, pyside2, qgraphicspathitem

I am puzzled by a difference of behaviour between `Qt5` (`PySide2`) and `Qt4` (`PySide`). I get the impression that `Qt5` has a bug but perhaps I do something wrong?

In short: when applying a computed `QPainterPath` to a `QGraphicsPathItem` (using `setPath`), the resulting size of the `QGraphicsPathItem` is **bigger** than the size of the `QPainterPath` itself by 1.5 pixels. This makes no sense to me, and with Qt4 the size was exactly the same.

I provide a simple piece of code to reproduce with both PySide and PySide2.

Using PySide:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class Foo (QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Foo, self).__init__()
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRect(0,0,10,10)
        print(str(path.boundingRect()))
        self.setPath(path)
        print(str(self.boundingRect()))

x=Foo(None)
```

And the result is:

```
$ python2 ./with_py2.py 
PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 0.000000, 10.000000, 10.000000)
PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 0.000000, 10.000000, 10.000000)
```

Same size, as expected. All good.

The exact same code with Qt5:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

class Foo (QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Foo, self).__init__()
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRect(0,0,10,10)
        print(str(path.boundingRect()))
        self.setPath(path)
        print(str(self.boundingRect()))

x=Foo(None)
```

results in:

```
$ python3 bug.py 
PySide2.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 0.000000, 10.000000, 10.000000)
PySide2.QtCore.QRectF(-0.500000, -0.500000, 11.000000, 11.000000)
```

Does anyone see any obvious explanation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundingRect depend on the QPen of the QGraphicsPathItem to calculate it as seen in the source code.

**[Qt4](https://github.com/qt/qt/blob/0a2f2382541424726168804be2c90b91381608c6/src/gui/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp#L8319):**

```
QRectF QGraphicsPathItem::boundingRect() const
{
    Q_D(const QGraphicsPathItem);
    if (d->boundingRect.isNull()) {
        qreal pw = pen().widthF();
        if (pw == 0.0)
            d->boundingRect = d->path.controlPointRect();
        else {
            d->boundingRect = shape().controlPointRect();
        }
    }
    return d->boundingRect;
}
```

**[Qt5](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp#L8447)**

```
QRectF QGraphicsPathItem::boundingRect() const
{
    Q_D(const QGraphicsPathItem);
    if (d->boundingRect.isNull()) {
        qreal pw = pen().style() == Qt::NoPen ? qreal(0) : pen().widthF();
        if (pw == 0.0)
            d->boundingRect = d->path.controlPointRect();
        else {
            d->boundingRect = shape().controlPointRect();
        }
    }
    return d->boundingRect;
}
```

And if you check the Qt docs in both versions you will see that there was a change in the values of the QPen created by default:

- [Qt4](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qpen.html#QPen):

> The default pen is a solid black brush with **0 width**, square cap style
>   (Qt::SquareCap), and bevel join style (Qt::BevelJoin).

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

- [Qt5](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpen.html#details):

> The default pen is a solid black brush with **1 width**, square cap style
>   (Qt::SquareCap), and bevel join style (Qt::BevelJoin).

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

If you want to observe PySide behavior in PySide2 then set a `QPen(Qt::NoPen)` to the `QGraphicsPathItem`:

```py
class Foo(QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.NoPen))
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRect(0, 0, 10, 10)
        print(str(path.boundingRect()))
        self.setPath(path)
        print(str(self.boundingRect()))


x = Foo()
```

Output

```
PySide2.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 0.000000, 10.000000, 10.000000)
PySide2.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 0.000000, 10.000000, 10.000000)
```

Comment: Thank you for this quick and accurate answer. Issue solved!